# Get D3D1211On12 example working using call to D3D11On12CreateDevice

Tags: rust, windows-rs

I'm trying to get the [C++ D3D1211On12 example](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D1211On12) working using windows-rs, but I can't get the call to [D3D11On12CreateDevice](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/blob/a20dbba3615051891225a0e07a36375c6a2a531a/crates/libs/windows/src/Windows/Win32/Graphics/Direct3D11on12/mod.rs#L6) to return a valid ID3D11Device.

The code I'm using is:

```rust
fn create_d11_device(pdevice: &ID3D12Device) -> Result<Option<*mut Option<windows::Win32::Graphics::Direct3D11::ID3D11Device>>> {
    unsafe {
        let ppdevice:Option<*mut Option<ID3D11Device>> = None;
        let ppimmediatecontext: Option<*mut Option<ID3D11DeviceContext>> = None;

        D3D11On12CreateDevice(pdevice, D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT.0, None, None, 0, 
            ppdevice, ppimmediatecontext, None  )?;

        Ok(ppdevice)
    }
}
```

Has anybody managed to this this call working?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to write this function is like this:

```rust
fn create_d11_device(pdevice: &ID3D12Device) -> Result<Option<ID3D11Device>> {
    unsafe {
        let mut ppdevice: Option<ID3D11Device> = None;
        let mut ppimmediatecontext: Option<ID3D11DeviceContext> = None;

        D3D11On12CreateDevice(pdevice, D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT.0, None, None, 0, 
            Some(&mut ppdevice), Some(&mut ppimmediatecontext), None  )?;

        Ok(ppdevice)
    }
}
```